# Why this python function has Twice Return?

Tags: python

I find a Python Function like below from Head First:

```
def san(string):
    if ':' in string:
        spliter = ':'
    elif '-' in string:
        spliter = '-'
    else:
        return string
    (key, value) = string.split(spliter)
    return (key, value)
```

why twice RETURN ?

Comment: the else applies to the elif, not the if at the top. The return at the bottom is still reachable

Answer (score 1):

One is for the case where the string is not split, the other is for the case where the string is split.

Comment: It's also fairly terrible code, because it would be hard to use in a consistent way. Not knowing if you'll get two returns or one, you end up having to type check or treat the return value as opaque. Not exactly ideal... This is why functions like `str.partition` exist, so you can get a consistent number of return values no matter what, making it more likely to be usable.

Comment: Thanks.  It is two different branch , I think by mistake.

Comment: @ShadowRanger it also scans the string three times. re.split might be a decent pythony solution worth sticking in an answer

Answer (score 1):

The return in the else clause is used to return ***before*** using the split function, returning the original string. The return at the bottom of the block is used to return the value ***after*** the split function has occurred.

Using multiple returns is common in most programming languages and is usually used to break out of a function when you know that you don't need to run the remainder of the function. It is very useful when you reach an exceptional condition, there you can just return a special case which the function caller can pick up and know that an error has occurred.

Do note however, that some people consider it to be bad style, especially if it causes inconsistent behaviour (like it does in your example).